# Can't add image to a class in tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to have an image in a window in tkinter in a class but i cant get it to work, without the image lines it shows an empty window but when I execute the code with the lines for the image, I get an error saying: `'Img_window' object has no attribute 'tk'.`

How can I change the code to show the image?

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Img_window:
    def __init__(self):

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Image")
    
        image_open = Image.open("welcome.jpg")
        welcome_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_open)

        image_label = Label(self, image = welcome_img)
        image_label.grid(row=1,columnspan=3)
    
        self.window.mainloop()

img_window = Img_window()
```

Comment: Exactly what "lines" are you talking about? I think your question might be a duplicate of [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Typo.  You have `Label(self, ...)` where you need `Label(self.window, ...)`.

Comment: You can't use a non-widget as the parent of a widget. `self` isn't a widget.

Comment: If it is a child window, use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk   #Added this
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk



class Img_window:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() #Fixed
        window.title("Image") #Fixed
            
        image_open = Image.open("welcome.jpg")
        welcome_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_open)

        image_label = Label(image = welcome_img) #fixed
        image_label.grid(row=1,columnspan=3)
            
        window.mainloop()

Img_window()
```

Your problem was beeing using self where you shouldn't and not importing tkinter as tk

```
    image_label = Label(self, image = welcome_img)


    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title("Image")
```

Comment: I forgot to teel you to add: import tkinter as tk

Comment: The import is completely unnecessary.  They're not referring to `tk` anywhere.

Comment: It is also recommended to *explicitly* specify the parent of a widget.

Answer (score -2):

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class VideoPlayer:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title("مشغل الفيديو")

        # إنشاء عنصر لعرض الفيديو
        self.video_label = tk.Label(window)
        self.video_label.pack()

        # فتح ملف الفيديو باستخدام OpenCV
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture("path/to/your/video/file.mp4")

        # تحديث الفيديو
        self.update_video()

    def update_video(self):
        # قراءة الإطار التالي من الفيديو
        ret, frame = self.video.read()

        if ret:
            # تحويل الإطار من تنسيق OpenCV إلى تنسيق صورة قابل للعرض بواسطة Tkinter
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = Image.fromarray(frame)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

            # عرض الإطار على عنصر Label في النافذة
            self.video_label.config(image=photo)
            self.video_label.image = photo

        # استدعاء تحديث الفيديو بشكل دوري
        self.window.after(10, self.update_video)

# إنشاء نافذة Tkinter
window = tk.Tk()

# إنشاء مشغل الفيديو
video_player = VideoPlayer(window)

# تشغيل البرنامج
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please translate the text and comments into English

Comment: We're talking about tkinter not OpenCV. @Tim Roberts had already solved problem.

Comment: How is this answer related to this question? Can you translate the comments and explain how does openCV relared in this answer?